# How can I quickly convert 3 SymPy Vectors to a 3x3 SymPy matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, vector, sympy

I have been using the SymPy Vector module to do Vector Calculus and related Physics. However, I would like to convert my created vectors to Matrix format. I know that there is a method of Vector.to_matrix(CoordSys), and I got it to work, but I am struggling with creating a 3x3 matrix for eventually finding determinants with.

My current code involves 3 individual vectors: Phidiffu, Phidiffv, and UnitVector. I am trying to insert these into a matrix, and it is sort of working, but I am unable to delete columns, and the method takes a suspiciously large amount of code for something that should be simple. N is the method that I sort of got to work, while m is the method that I could not get to work.

```
import math as m
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import *
from sympy.physics.vector import *

u, v, Phi = symbols('u v Phi')
Phi = Function('Phi')(u, v)
F = Function('F')(x, y)

N = CoordSys3D('N')

Phi = (2*u*cos(v))*N.i + (2*u*sin(v))*N.j + (u)*N.k
PhiMat = Phi.to_matrix(N)
PhiVec = matrix_to_vector(PhiMat, N)

Phidiffu = Phi.diff(u)
Phidiffv = Phi.diff(v)
UnitVector = N.i + N.j + N.k

UnitVectorMat = UnitVector.to_matrix(N)
PhidiffuMat = Phidiffu.to_matrix(N)
PhidiffvMat = Phidiffv.to_matrix(N)

UnitVectorMat.col_join(PhidiffuMat)

M = Matrix([UnitVectorMat, PhidiffuMat, PhidiffvMat])
#M = Matrix([UnitVectorMat], [PhidiffuMat], [PhidiffvMat])
#M = Matrix(1, 3, [UnitVectorMat, PhidiffuMat, PhidiffvMat])
#M = Matrix(3, 1, [[UnitVectorMat], [PhidiffuMat], [PhidiffvMat]])

N1 = zeros(3)
N2 = N1.col_insert(0, UnitVectorMat)
N3 = N2.col_insert(1, PhidiffuMat)
N4 = N3.col_insert(2, PhidiffvMat)
N5 = N4.col_del(3)
#N6 = N5.col_del(3)
#N7 = N6.col_del(3)
#N7.T
N4
```

Does anyone know how I may get the code to work?

- Best regards, ExactPlace441

Comment: Usually we ask posters to explain what "does not work".  I suppose you could wait till one one of us runs your code and does that for you :(

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, `I could not get to work`, this does not specify any details about what is your error, stackoverflow to read [how to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can concatenate matrices horizontally with `Matrix.hstack(M1, M2, M3)`

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit about my issue. I stated in the beginning "I am struggling with creating a 3x3 matrix", so I was implying that my issue was that I could not create a 3x3 matrix from 3 vectors.